# Divergence theorem in Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, divergence-operator, trace-map

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a regular domain (a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary) and let $X$ be a $W^{1,1}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a Sobolev vector field. I want to prove the following version of the **divergence theorem**:

$$\int_{\Omega} \text{div}(X)=\int_{\partial\Omega} \text{Tr}(X)\cdot \nu$$

where $\text{Tr}$ is the trace operator. Clearly the theorem is true if $X\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^N)$ because of the classical divergence theorem. Otherwise we can find a sequence of $\{X_n\}\subseteq  C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^N)$ converging to $X$. And clearly

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\Omega} \text{div}(X_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\partial\Omega} \text{Tr}(X_n)\cdot \nu$$

If we can exchange limits and integral we've done because $\text{div}$ and $\text{Tr}$ are continous operators. But why can we do it?

I'm trying to apply dominated convergence but without any success.

Comment: Be careful: the continuity of $\text{div}$ and $\text{Tr}$ is actually from $W^{1,1}$ to $L^1$. With that in mind though, this should hopefully simplify things a lot.

Comment: How does this help me in exchanging limit and integral?

Comment: Are you suggesting me to dominate definitely $|\text{div}(X_n)|$ with $|\text{div}(X)|+C$  (where $C$ is a constant)? And the same for trace?

Comment: The thing is you probably shouldn't try to exchange the limit and the integral, I'm not sure you'd get somewhere. Try instead to think of $X\mapsto \int_\Omega \text{div} (X)$ and $X\mapsto \int_{\partial\Omega} \text{Tr}(X)\cdot\nu$ as operators from $W^{1,1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and show that they're continuous (using the $W^{1,1}\to L^1$ continuity of $\text{div}$ and $\text{Tr}$).

Comment: Is integration $\int_{\Omega}: L^1(\Omega)\to \mathbb{R}$ continous?

Comment: Yup! You can simply use the fact that it's linear and that $|\int f| \leq \int |f| = ||f||_{L^1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)